# Putting Text over Image while being responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do i place text over image div in certain position while keeping it responsive(doesn't move from that spot on smaller devices or bigger)
Problem im getting is that most of the content wont fit like i want it or wont even stick to image in smaller devices, so i need solution on how to solve this one,placing 3 text divs on image div without using method of making background image, i need it to work with  tag
Bootstrap v4

i tried this:

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJmWQw)

```
<div class="slider">
            <div class="cover-image">
              <div class="image-link">
                <div class="image-date">
                  <p>08.10.2017</p>
                </div>
                <div class="image-text">
                  <div class="img-test"><h2>Gradjevina koja se gradi duze od egipatskih piramida</h2></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">Eskterijer</a>
              </div>
              <img class="img-fluid" src="@asset('/images/slider-1.png')">
            </div>
          </div>
```

and CSS:

```css
.cover-image {
  position: relative;
}

.slider .image-link {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.img-test {
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: none;
}

.slider .image-date {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 10px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="cover-image">
    <div class="image-link">
      <div class="image-date">
        <p>08.10.2017</p>
      </div>
      <div class="image-text">
        <div class="img-test">
          <h2>Gradjevina koja se gradi duze od egipatskih piramida</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#">Eskterijer</a>
    </div>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://vietlongtravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/151548909_high-770x530.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: currently your text over image...what do you want now?

Comment: To stick to that div (img div) when scaling down to other screen sizes

Comment: You can just use the @media query in adjusting those divs in other screen resolutions.